# Can php that was run externally locate the page name that it was told to run form?

Tags: php, html

I've got an html page (my server is set up to parse html as php) and in the html page, I `include_once` a php script. I need to get the html page name (with the extension) but I can't seem to get that without grabbing the page name of the script that's running the php.

If that didn't make sense, I'll try explaining another way.

Inside `example.html` I  `<?php include_once 'example.php'; ?>`

I then need the `example.php` page to get the `example.html` page name.

Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by page name?

Comment: Well, you can be super witty about it, specify a variable and then include your file. `$coming_from = 'my_ultra_super_page.html'; include('example.php');` and voila, bulletproof.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: The command `var_dump($_SERVER);` may help.

Comment: @N.B: "voilà", with an accent. OP: you can do this with the PHP debug_backtrace() function that provides you the call stack. By navigating in it, you could retrieve the calling file. http://php.net/manual/fr/function.debug-backtrace.php

Comment: This has nothing to do with CONSTANTS. You can include things on a file that is included.

Comment: I would also say, parsing html files as php added extra work for the server when a html file might not even contain said php. a better solution would be to serve up the php file and include the html instead. at least then php has a reason for being called upon and when you dont need php just go with a normal html file to be served up. if the php extension is your concern. Look into url rewriting, you can take a url with .html and server the php file instead if that html file doesnt exist.

Comment: In addition to my last comment, read the docs on http://php.net/manual/fr/function.debug-backtrace.php and you'll see in the "Examples" section that the exact solution you need is provided :)

Comment: A smart man on SO once wrote that common sense is a super power. I really hate seeing that he was so damn right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]
```

in example.php should contain example.html.

See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php